# Kubernetes pod not READY

Tags: kubernetes

I am super new to Kubernetes.  I have inherited a side project - really an in progress POC - from another developer that recently left the team.  He did a demo from a VM that we still have access to before he abruptly left.  After he left we were able to go through his demo and things were working.  One of the team members restarted the VM and now things are broken.  I've been assigned to figure things out.  I've been able to bring all the components back up aside from the Kubernetes part which all stack traces point to being the issue at the moment.

As mentioned I am new to Kubernetes, so I lack the vocabulary to do proper searches online.

I have ran a few commands have pasted their output below.  If I understand correctly the issue is with the k8s deployment not running:
kubectl get all

```
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IPPORT(S)  AGE                                                 AGE
service/kubernetes          ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>              443/TCP                                             14d
service/app-service-5x7z    NodePort    10.96.215.11    <none>              3000:32155/TCP,3001:32762/TCP,27017:30770/TCP       3d

NAME                                    READY   UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/app-deployment-5x7z     0/1     1           0           3d

NAME                                    DESIRED     CURRENT     READY       AGE
replicaset.apps/app-deployment-5x7z     1           1           0           3d
```

I'm guessing that the issue is with the fact that the READY state is **0/1**

Can someone please guide me as to how I can bring this guy back up?  Also, I see a lot of heavy documentation online, is there a place with a shallow bank that I can dive into the work of Kubernetes.  I'm very excited about this opportunity, but it just hasn't been a smooth start.

Comment: Share output of `kubectl get all` command in given namespace and `kubectl describe deployment app-deployment-5x7z`

Comment: Do a `kubectl describe pod` and paste the output

Comment: Thanks @DT. Is the output above not what you wanted regarding "kubectl get all"?
Here's the output of kubectl describe deployment: https://justpaste.it/72owe

Comment: @paltaa, here's the output of what you requested: https://justpaste.it/47mw3

Comment: You have a network problem, try running `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`

Comment: this is your error: networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "app-deployment-5x7z-7f47987c76-f8pbk_default" network: open /run/flannel/subnet.env: no such file or directory

Comment: also do a `kubectl describe node`

Comment: here's the output of kubectl describe node: https://justpaste.it/21f70

Comment: paltaa, not sure which way to go about things based on our convo.  should i run the kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0.0/16, or add the missing file to /run/flannel, which has the following:
FLANNEL_NETWORK=10.244.0.0/16
FLANNEL_SUBNET=10.244.0.1/24
FLANNEL_MTU=1450
FLANNEL_IPMASQ=true

also, could you please tell me what made you suggest running the kubeadmin init --pod-network... command?

Comment: @paltaa so the issue is from the missing file.  could you tell me how to get things started up correctly once I've placed the file in /run/flannel/?

Comment: run the command kubeadm init should fix it

Comment: Thanks @paltaa. i get a different error now: https://justpaste.it/6c7hx
Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Hi @HandsomeWayfarer please try following the `kubeadm reset` steps below on the provided answer to see if you get rid of the error, if not, update your question with the current state so you can keep helping you. I see you mention you'd like to understand more about Kubernetes, I can provide you a answer adding all the theoretical knowledge related to your question if you'd like, just let me know.

Comment: thanks @willrof, please see my comments to the answer below.

Comment: @HandsomeWayfarer I'm following you comments in the answer bellow, I see you are having dificulties redeploying your environment after kubeadm reset. In order to help you further, you need to find the yaml files responsible for deploying the cluster. you can add them to your original question and I can give you a step by step on how to run them. It's probably called `app-deployment` or something similar. let me know and I'll help you.

Comment: Thanks, @willrof.  So i went through this guide (https://learnk8s.io/nodejs-kubernetes-guide) and it was very helpful.  I'm working through the deployment now.  The problem is that the previous developer left like 20 different yaml files around (i'm not kidding).  so i'm sifting through them to see which one will work.  most likely none will and i'll have to modify it to work.  i'll keep you posted.  thanks for the support.  knowing someone is willing to assist is always a good feeling.  appreciate it.

Comment: @willrof, here's my current situation.  since i have no idea what this guy used, i built the docker images, and i updated the service and deployment yaml files to use them. I then ran `kubectl apply -f <yaml_folder>` which succeeds, but when i run `kubectl get pods --watch` i see the following: https://justpaste.it/3p9r1

any suggestions how i could debug and get to the root cause?  my understanding is that it's not able to pull the docker image.  but since i just created it and it's located on the same machine (not in a registry), not sure what the problem is.  thanks.

Comment: @HandsomeWayfarer if the docker image is in the local registry of the node, you have to set `imagePullPolicy: Never` on the deployment file. You mention there is a lot of files, but since it created only this deployment, should be relatively easy to find the yaml with `kind: Deployment` that matches the name of the pod. [PrePulledImages](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#pré-pulled-images)

Comment: Thanks @wilrof.  setting the imagePullPolicy to Never did the trick.

Comment: @HandsomeWayfarer I'm glad it helped you solve your issue! I've compiled my help into an answer and I'd really appreciate if you could consider to click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it, that way others know that you were sufficiently helped. And consider choosing one and marking as accepted clicking the checkmark (✓) if it answered your question. Also take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you haven't yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing down my two cents on your solution:

- After you did the `kubeadm reset` and `kubeadm init` your cluster was empty.

**1st Problem:**

> I applied those changes, but now when i run `kubectl get all` i only get the first line "service/kubernetes" and i no longer get anything regarding `app-service-5x7z`
>   any chance you could give me a hint as to how to accomplish that [getting back the deployment]?

**Solution:**

- You need to find the yaml files responsible for deploying the cluster, it's probably called  `app-deployment`  or something similar.

---

**2nd Issue:**

> Here's my current situation. Since I have no idea what this guy used, i built the docker images, and i updated the service and deployment yaml files to use them. I then ran  `kubectl apply -f <yaml_folder>`  which succeeds, but when i run  `kubectl get pods --watch`  i see the following:  [justpaste.it/3p9r1](https://justpaste.it/3p9r1)  any suggestions how i could debug and get to the root cause? my understanding is that it's not able to pull the docker image. but since i just created it and it's located on the same machine (not in a registry), not sure what the problem is.

**Solution:**

From [PrePulledImages](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#pr%C3%A9-pulled-images) Documentation:

> By default, the kubelet will try to pull each image from the specified registry. However, if the  `imagePullPolicy`  property of the container is set to  `IfNotPresent`  or  `Never`, then a local image is used (preferentially or exclusively, respectively).
>   All pods will have read access to any pre-pulled images.

If a docker image is in the local registry of the node, you have to set `imagePullPolicy: Never` on the deployment file. Note that the image must be present on all nodes local repositories to ensure availability.

It's good also to create a [Docker Hub Private Repository](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/#private-repositories) to ensure availability and integrity.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the node by

```
kubeadm reset -f
```

Cleanup old flannel installation

```
rm -rf /var/lib/cni/
rm -rf /run/flannel
rm -rf /etc/cni/

ip link delete cni0
ip link delete flannel.1
```

and then install Kubernetes

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

Install flannel

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/2140ac876ef134e0ed5af15c65e414cf26827915/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Comment: thanks.  i applied those changes, but now when i run `kubectl get all` i only get the first line "service/kubernetes" and i no longer get anything regarding `app-service-5x7z`

Comment: That is expected...now the cluster is reset and you need apply pods and service yamls again

Comment: any chance you could give me a hint as to how to accomplish that?

Comment: you can do kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml